# Uncaught ReferenceError: FullCalendar is not defined (Webpack/NPM)

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

When i load my page, calendar not working and on my console i have :

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: FullCalendar is not defined ReferenceError: FullCalendar is not defined
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://admin.test/agenda:279:20)
at mightThrow (http://admin.test/js/admin.js:30047:29)
at process (http://admin.test/js/admin.js:30115:12) undefined

admin.js:30340 Uncaught ReferenceError: FullCalendar is not defined
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (agenda:279)
at mightThrow (admin.js:30047)
at process (admin.js:30115)
```

---

1) I have a laravel project with "AdminLTE 3.0.5".

Package.json :

```
    "devDependencies": {
    "@fullcalendar/bootstrap": "^4.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^4.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^4.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^4.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^4.4.0",
    "admin-lte": "^3.0.5",
    "axios": "^0.19",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.13",
    "popper.js": "^1.12",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
    "sass": "^1.20.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
},
```

---

2) I import Fullcalendar package with my webpack :

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js/app.js')
.js('resources/js/calendar.js', 'public/js/calendar.js')
```

app.js :

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});

require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/draggable');
require('admin-lte');

/* Table */
require('../../node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js');
require('../../node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/datatables-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js');
require('../../node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/datatables-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js');
require('../../node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/datatables-responsive/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js');
require('../../node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/bs-custom-file-input/bs-custom-file-input.min.js');
```

calendar.js :

```
/* Calendar */
require('@fullcalendar/core');
require('@fullcalendar/daygrid');
require('@fullcalendar/timegrid');
require('@fullcalendar/interaction');
require('@fullcalendar/bootstrap');
```

---

3) On my vue, i copy/past the AdminLTE3 [calendar page](https://adminlte.io/themes/v3/pages/calendar.html) and only add my 2 mix file before  :

```
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script> 
<script src="{{ mix('js/calendar.js') }}"></script> 

<script>
  $(function () {

    /* initialize the external events
     -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
    function ini_events(ele) {
      ele.each(function () {
[...]
```

---

I use "require()" function to call all js files, and when i run "**npm run dev**", everything work, no error. 
I think that it's a js file order, but it's the same order than [AdminLTE3 calendar page](https://adminlte.io/themes/v3/pages/calendar.html)... or i'm blind.
I changed all versions of the calendar package  & jquery & jquery-ui to have the same that this page (4.4.0 for my dl version).

Someone can help me pls ?

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution.

Imports files like that on my calendar.js :

```
/* Calendar */
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import dayGrid from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGrid from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import interaction, { Draggable } from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import bootstrap from '@fullcalendar/bootstrap';
```

And you dont need this 2 lines on my script

```
<!--
    var Calendar = FullCalendar.Calendar;
    var Draggable = FullCalendarInteraction.Draggable;
-->
```

Comment: That not work :/... i have "Uncaught ReferenceError: FullCalendar is not defined"